# Express routing issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I am learning expressjs and I've been stuck at moment how to make the navigation between pages:

What I've done:

1. Installed express, and converted regular html to jade format.

2. In **app.js** I've added following code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/index.jade', { title: 'index' });
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/portfolio.jade', { title: 'about' });
});
```

3. All files I've stored in views folder and in index.jade I've added following code:

   ```
         a.selected(href='/views/index.jade') TIMELINE
         a(href='/views/portfolio.jade') PORTFOLIO
         a(href='/views/about_me.jade') ABOUT ME
         a(href='/views/store.jade') STORE
   ```
4. When I click on portfolio button, the following error appears:
   [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually creating routes, which enable a browser to ask the server for data on a specific path. What the server sends to the browser based on that path is up to the programmer.

In your case, you're internally configuring the `/about` route to render the file `views/portfolio.jade`.

Thus, instead of linking to the `.jade` files like you're doing, you should be linking to the actual routes you created:

```
  a.selected(href='/') TIMELINE
  a(href='/portfolio') PORTFOLIO
  a(href='/about') ABOUT ME
  a(href='/store') STORE
```

Assuming you have the following routes:

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/index.jade', { title: 'index' });
});

app.get('/about', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/about_me.jade', { title: 'about' });
});

app.get('/store', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/store.jade', { title: 'store' });
});

app.get('/portfolio', function(req, res){
  res.render('views/portfolio.jade', { title: 'portfolio' });
});
```

Comment: Same answer provided.

Comment: Thank you guys, Florian and Lucas. I really appreciate your help, have a nice day and take care!

Answer (score 2):

You need to link `href` the `route` path:

```
a.selected(href='/') TIMELINE
      a(href='/about') PORTFOLIO
      a(href='/about') ABOUT ME
      a(href='/store') STORE
```